# How to use INSERT, SELECT and SET together?

Tags: mysql, sql, select, insert, set

I have to insert someone into a table, using INSERT SELECT and using parameters (The assignment says explicitly: 'For example: SET @param').

I have used both INSERT SELECT and INSERT SET separately to insert someone into a table, but I dont know how to combine those statements together.

```
    INSERT INTO Customer (FirstName,LastName,City,Country)

    SELECT FirstName,LastName,City, Country FROM Employee
    WHERE City = 'New York';
```

Kind of like that, but I have to also insert Phone, PostalCode, Email, and other stuff, using SET fieldN = 'Something'. The thing is, I dont know how nor where to fit the SET statements into that code.

Comment: Can you tag your kind of db (mysql or ms-sqlserver ...) and give some sample data ?

Comment: Can you pls share your DB design or code...

Answer (score 0):

Here is the syntax for `INSERT INTO ... SELECT`:

```
INSERT INTO yourTable (col1, col2)
SELECT colA, colB
FROM otherTable;
```

You may direct the output from a `SELECT` into an `INSERT` statement in most flavors of SQL.  You may add more columns if needed, and you can also substitute a column for a variable, e.g. `@param`.

Answer (score 0):

```html
INSERT INTO table_name [ (column1 [, column2 ]) ]
SELECT [ *|column1 [, column2 ]
FROM table1 [, table2 ]
[ WHERE VALUE OPERATOR ];
```